# rsync with -X fails due to dot underscore files

Tags: macos, rsync

I need to maintain sync copy from one external drive to another, on my macOS (Monterey).

ext drive 1 (source) = ExFAT
ext drive 2 (target) = APFS
rsync v3.2.3 is used (not macOS default v2.6.9)

`rsync -aAXNHuhE /Volumes/sourceSSD /Volumes/targetSSD`

This results in error:
`rsync: [sender] get_xattr_names: llistxattr("/Volumes/sourceSSD/pics/._A1099.JPG",1024) failed: Operation not permitted (1)`

This is happening due to use of `-X` flag (to copy extended attributes). There are also accompanying dot underscore files `._` which I understand is where macOS stores extended attr.

Expectedly, direct use of `xattr` as well throws error.
`xattr -l /Volumes/sourceSSD/pics/._A1099.JPG`
error: `xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Volumes/sourceSSD/pics/._A1099.JPG'`

I do not want to let go of extended attributes by removing `-X`.
Why is xattr failing on these dot underscore files?
How to run rsync successfully in such case?

I've seen similar questions, but none that is about working while keeping `-X` (extended attributes).

Comment: you may get better results with ditto. See: https://ss64.com/osx/ditto.html

Comment: Where did you get rsync? I highly recommend Homebrew for easy installation of linux-like stuff. See: https://brew.sh/index_de

Comment: ditto doesn't seem to work with delta sync, rsync does

Comment: yes, rsync 3.x is picked from brew